# System to adjust ropes to different lengths

Tags: home

I could sure use help with something to adjust the 2 ropes to different lengths.

Both ropes are adjusted to about the same length, so the small platform
that the ropes go to, is level. The platform is used to hold a book for reading purposes.

As it is now, the 2 ropes are just tied around the screw coming out of the wall.

All I could think of is some type of cleats like they use in sailing.

The ropes are used for lifting about 5 lbs of weight.

[image: Rope suspended from two points]

Does someone have other ideas?

This is what the other end looks like.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the result you want to have in the end?

Answer (score 3):

there is a little device used on tent ropes to take up slack and adjust their length. It's basically a flat piece of metal tied onto the end of the rope that has a hole in it through which the other end of the rope is threaded. They are simple and effective. Someone who works in an outdoor store or a camping supply store can tell you what it's called and show you how to use it.

Comment: I looked at those at a store that sells sailing accesories.

Answer (score -1):

I have good ideas given. I went with this found at stores with sailing supplies.

[image]

Comment: great!   glad you found something useful.      -NN